# jQuery: Let events run after each other(queue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, loops, queue

I am looking for a way to prevent events from running all at once, so they have to run in the right order, so the event before that has to be done. I have seen that you can use jQuery queue for that but i cant seem to get it working.

The example is a simple 'show a msg' in a placeholder idea(they have to wait for each other to finish).

I have used 2 links in the example code but there are more. Here is a small example of the idea/code.

```
    $('.link-1').click(function(e){

        $.plugin.show({
             text: 'Quisque porta purus et odio vulputate ornare. Suspendisse dui dui.',
             time: 1000
        });
    });

    $('.link-2').click(function(e){

        $.plugin.show({
             text: 'Etiam non augue nec felis consectetur sodales a.',
             time: 4000
        });
    });


    // public functions
    $.plugin= {
        show: function(str){

            var tmp = '<div class="msg-box">'+str.text+'</div>';

            $('#msg-div').prepend(tmp);

            $('.msg-box').fadeIn(str.time, function(){
                $(this).delay(str.time).fadeOut(str.time, function(){
                     $(this).remove();
                }):
            });
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Events never run "all at once"; only one event is ever being handled at any given time in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's queue is specially designed for animation and is an **element scope** object, which means there is no **global animation queue** provided to satisfy your requirement.

Since you always create a brand new `.msg-div` element in `$.plugin.show` method, all these message divs are not the same element, so that you cannot reuse the same animation queue.

For your requirement, [Flow-JS](https://github.com/willconant/flow-js) may be a better option, including it and write your code like this:

```
    $.plugin = {
        show: function(str, callback /* 1. add an callback argument */) {
            var tmp = '<div class="msg-box">' + str.text + '</div>';

            $('body').prepend(tmp);

            $('.msg-box').fadeIn(
                str.time, 
                function() {
                    $(this).delay(str.time).fadeOut(
                        str.time, 
                        function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                            callback(); /* 2. run callback here */
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    };

    flow.exec(
        function() {
            $.plugin.show(
                { text: 'abc', time: 4000 },
                this /* 3. provide this as callback parameter to $.plugin.show */
            );
        },
        function() {
            $.plugin.show(
                { text: 'xyz', time: 1000 },
                this /* 3. provide this as callback parameter to $.plugin.show */
            );
        }
    );
```

You should simply add a `callback` parameter to your `$.plugin.show` method, and execute all animating function using `flow.exec` method, providing `this` as the `callback` parameter when invoking `$.plugin.show` method.

Comment: okay i will take a look at this plugin, but the example that you have provided isn't something that i want to use(it should be like the example above) But that for the info that queue is used for animations.

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin function you are missing a '

```
$.plugin= {
    show: function(str){
        var tmp = '<div class="msg-box">'+str.text+'</div>';

        $('#msg-div').prepend(tmp);

        // $(.msg-box').fadeIn(str.time, function(){
        $('.msg-box').fadeIn(str.time, function(){
            $(this).delay(str.time).fadeOut(str.time, function(){
                $(this).remove();
             }):
        });
    } 
}
```

Edit also on your plugin.show calls you have too many commas

```
$.plugin.show({
     text: 'Quisque porta purus et odio vulputate ornare. Suspendisse dui dui.',
     time: 1000//,
});
```